# Is it possible to backward search through the `Alpine` inbox?

Tags: email, search, alpine-mail

I am using `Alpine` (formerly Pine) for email.  I can search for words in the inbox using `w` and the keyword.  However this searches from the oldest to the newest items which is not always efficient when I have a lot of emails in my inbox and I am looking for a recent item.

Is it possible to get Alpine to search from the newest to the oldest items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are comfortable building it from source code.
(If you use features with external dependencies, such as LDAP
and Kerberos, then this may be somewhat tricky.)

See
http://mailman2.u.washington.edu/pipermail/alpine-info/2009-February/001753.html

Steps are:

download the .bin

apply it to the Alpine source code using "patch"

run the build per the normal instructions.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I had kinda given up hope on this question...  I will definitely give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you know roughly the date range within which you wish to search, you can first search on date (;d) then narrow the search (;n) with text. Although it will still search forwards, it will be a lot quicker if you know you're searching for something that arrived within the last month etc.
B-30